Do I need cement for ENT and if yes, can I use PVC cement?
Companion question to How to connect ENT to boxes and why is the nut missing?
I am installing PVC boxes and ENT with the fittings from the linked question (fitting + metal locknut).
Do I need additional cement for this or is it ok to just use the fittings?
I have seen somewhere there is Carlon cement but I can’t find it anywhere (in typical big box stores). If it is necessary, is it ok to just use normal PVC cement?

why do you want to use cement?

I do NOT want to, my question is if I have to :)

ENT fittings snap-on
While cementing ENT to a standard PVC fitting will work (ENT is made of PVC), dedicated ENT fittings are designed to snap onto ENT instead of being cemented on, so there is no need for cement in your application.
